# Swift RestKit Problems

Tags: swift2, restkit, mlab

I have installed RestKit in my Swift application. I can't find good documentation to get it to work in swift. This is what I have. I have also never used a rest API. I am connecting to MongoLab.

```
class Users: NSObject {
  var users: String = ""
  var url : String = ""
}

let mapDict = ["users":"users","url":"url"]

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {

    let objectManager = RKObjectManager(HTTPClient: client)

    let mapDict = ["news":"news","url":"url"]
    let usersMapping = RKObjectMapping(forClass: Users.self)
    usersMapping.addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary(mapDict)

    let responseDescriptor:RKResponseDescriptor = RKResponseDescriptor(mapping: usersMapping,
        method: RKRequestMethod.GET,
        pathPattern: dburl,
        keyPath: nil,
        statusCodes: NSIndexSet(index: 200))

    let response = RKResponseDescriptor(mapping: usersMapping, method: RKRequestMethod.GET, pathPattern: dburl, keyPath: nil, statusCodes: NSIndexSet(index: 200))

    RKObjectManager.addResponseDescriptor(response)
```

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restkit in Swift Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28165763/restkit-in-swift-project)

Comment: I fixed this by deleting the app and recreating it. Not sure what happened. I ended up using Alamofire & SwiftyJSON rather than restkit. Much better documentation it seems and less code.